# How to design a cloud infrastructure for embedded android / linux consumer products?

Tags: android, cloud, product

We are developing consumer products for smarthome applications. These products use Android / embedded linux as OS. We would like to:

1) Be able to update firmware and userspace APPs remotely ( which we can do via LAN/WAN network succesfully via command line)

2) Be able to monitor exceptions from android products.

3) Provide network services such as weather, time, RSS, money market...etc

We would like to design a server infrastructure, which we call as "cloud", to be able to provide above services. The system we propose uses linux as the OS.

For the server side, which tools would be convenient for vertical and horizontal scalability ? Which programming languages / frameworks (such as NodeJS) would be timesaving ? Are there any examples for such systems on the market?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are examples - Google itself is the one ;-)

But even Google does not updates firmware - you need to be an Android device manufacturer to publish new firmwares. Even in this case - only yours devices can be upgraded.

To monitor apps failures - ACRA is a default choice. Usually, apps developers incorporate it into their apps.

The architecture will deeply depends on your performance and reliability demands, your users geographical distribution will also influence.

If you intend to be a global player - developing such an architecture will be a great challenge, if you will hire me. Feel free to contact me.

Comment: waww, thank you very much for ACRA. we use custom/modified firmwares for our needs, therefore we sometimes need to be able to update them. Of course, they are just for our products, not the others. For the performance, please consider tens of thousands of villas/residences in every country. Wat we want to have is a global server cloud, which runs a common software to control/monitor each of our products. And I will contact with you also :)

Comment: Looks interesting. I updated my profile to make email visible publicly.

Comment: @SertacTULLUK, I can't see any mails from your email in my server logs :-( Please resend.

Comment: Just sent 2nd email from my gmail account.